# Finite product exists implies finite coproduce exist.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

> Let $C$ be a category such that the law composition of morphisms is bilinear, and there exists a zero object $0$, and the **products** exists for arbitrary finite sets of objects of $C$.
>
> Then the **coproducts** exist for arbitrary finite sets of objects of $C$.

It's actually exercise 2 of section 6.1 of Jacobson's Basic Algebra 2. It gives hints as follows:

> Let $(A,p_1,p_2)$ be a product of $A_1,A_2$ in $C$, $(A_1,1_{A_1},0)$ be the product of $A_1, 0$, then by property of product, there exists a unique $i_1:A_1\rightarrow A$, s.t. $p_1i_1=1_{A_1}, p_2i_1=0.$ Similarly we get a unique $i_2: A_2\rightarrow A$ s.t. $p_2i_2=1_{A_2}, p_1i_2=0.$
>
> Then $(i_1p_1+i_2p_2)i_1=i_1$ and $(i_1p_1+i_2p_2)i_2=i_2$, hence $i_1p_1+i_2p_2=1_A.$

My question is how to prove that $i_1p_1+i_2p_2=1_A$? I have tried different diagrams but didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has
$$
p_2( i_1p_1+i_2p_2)=p_2i_1p_1+p_2i_2p_2=0p_1+1p_2=p_2=p_21_A
$$
and
$$
p_1( i_1p_1+i_2p_2)=p_1i_1p_1+p_1i_2p_2=1p_1+0p_2=p_1=p_11_A.
$$
Hence, by uniqueness of the morphism $f\colon A\rightarrow A$ such that $p_1f=p_1$ and $p_2f=p_2$ one has
$$
i_1p_1+i_2p_2=1_A.
$$